# How do you get a number count (from another site) on a website?

Tags: javascript, python, numbers

I'm making a website, and I'd like to have my Duolingo XP numbers on the website. is there anyway to do that to have it refresh once a day? what language do you even code that in? is that even possible? I'm an avid html coder but I haven't really gone to anything more complex yet, I'm not really sure how to start on this

I don't really know what to do. literally any pointer in the right direction is appreciated :)

Comment: you need to look for an api for duolingo, try searching on google for that (an api is like a way for the computer to communicate with a website through code)

Answer (score 0):

To extend upon what @codingStarter said, you can make a request to Duolingo's API. This will have to be done from your backend to avoid issues with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

If you don't have a backend (you're simply writing pure HTML or something), then this probably won't work for you as is but nevertheless, here's an example written in JavaScript that would work in Node.js 18 (or earlier versions with `node-fetch`):

```js
async function getDuolingoXp(username)
{   
    const rawResponse = await fetch(`https://www.duolingo.com/2017-06-30/users?username=${ username }`);
    
    const response = await rawResponse.json();
    
    // Note: Duolingo's API returns an array of users, even though they only return one
    //  So just get the first one
    const duolingoUser = response.users[0];
    
    const totalXp = duolingoUser.totalXp;

    return totalXp;
}

// Note: Obviously, pass YOUR username here.
getDuolingoXp("YOUR_USERNAME_HERE")
    .then((totalXp) =>
    {
        console.log(`You have ${ totalXp } XP on Duolingo.`);
    });
```

I should add that this API is **not** documented publicly so maybe be careful about using it.

I learned of this endpoint by looking at the code for the [duolingo-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/duolingo-api?activeTab=explore) npm module (see `src/Duolingo.js`) and also found requests being made to it by observing the Network tab of the developer tools in Firefox while on the Duolingo website.